# Matching two arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, function, loops

I have the following two arrays in Scala:

```
val array1 = Array("Football","Tennis","Tennis","Golf","Cricket","BasketBall","Golf")

val array2 = Array("Golf","Tennis","Formula1","Rugby")
```

I want to return the distinct words which match across both arrays. So as "Tennis" and "Golf" appear twice, we would count them as one. I believe you would just do `array1.distinct` to begin with. I was wondering however, how do I put this into a Scala function?

Answer (score 1):

This is the obvious solution:

```
(array1.toSet intersect array2.toSet).toArray
```

However `Array` is not a full Scala type, so better to use `Vector` or `List` depending on how you intended to process the data. The Scala collections have a richer set of methods and inter-operate better.